# Angular: View is not rendering after POST and GET

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am very new to Angular.js, and I am starting to learn it by building a small project alone the way. I am really excited that it works properly for sending out POST request and Get data from server side. But I had a problem that I couldn't re-render my page after I made POST request and then GET new data (which I newly created). View is still showing my old data. Can anyone take a look at it and tell me where is the problem? I got the information back on the console, but the page is not rendering. No error has been caught during the process. Thanks~

View:

```
<div ng-class="{'tab-pane active': activeTab === 6, 'tab-pane' : activeTab !== 6}">
 <h2>Grill Recipe</h2>
 <hr>
 <div ng-controller="userRecipeController" ng-init="initGet()">
  <ul ng-repeat="recipe in userRecipes | filter: {category: 'Grill'}">
    <li>{{ recipe.name }}</li>
    <li>{{ recipe.category}}</li>
    <li>{{ recipe.ingredients }}</li>
    <li>{{ recipe.instructions }}</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.initGet = function() {
  recipesFactory.getRecipes()
  .then(function(result) {
     $scope.userRecipes = [];
     var userId = simpleStorage.get('userId');
     var recipeArr = result.data.recipes;
     for (var i = 0; i < recipeArr.length; i++) {
        var obj = recipeArr[i];
        if (obj.user_id === userId) {
             console.log("this is ", obj)
             $scope.userRecipes.push(obj)
         }
       }
     }, function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log("Error getting user recipes from the api");
          alert("Error getting user recipes from the api");
   });
};

$scope.activeTab = 0;
$scope.setActiveTab = function(tabToSet) {
  $scope.activeTab = tabToSet;
  $scope.initGet();
};
```

Factory:

```
(function recipesFactoryIIFE(){

       var recipesFactory = function($http){
            var recipesAPI = {};

            recipesAPI.getRecipes = function(){
              return $http.get('http://localhost:3000/recipes');
            };

            return recipesAPI;
        };

  recipesFactory.$inject = ['$http'];

 angular.module('recipesApp').factory('recipesFactory', recipesFactory);
 })();
```

Console:[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgsb9.png) and [hereAgain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38a3a.png)

Comment: What does `recipesFactory.getRecipes` look like?

Comment: can you make sure that it goes inside `if (obj.user_id === userId)` . I dont see _this is ..._ in the console snap

Comment: Your console shows the second call was succesful. If the second time your code reached `$scope.userRecipes = [];`, then at least your current data should get cleared in your view, instead of showing your old data, whether the second call enters inside `if (obj.user_id === userId)` or not, as @KaushalNiraula asked. Please, put a `console.log('cleared')` imediatelly after `$scope.userRecipes = [];` (also do what they asked) and try again.

Comment: @Chris I have upload Factory file in there, please let me know if you have any suggestion.

Comment: @KaushalNiraula I put whole version of the console in here and hereAgain, let me know if you have any suggestion.

Comment: @Alisson I put the "cleared" under userRecipes array and snap whole console at hereAgain, please let me know if you have any suggestion.

Comment: @tina just a shot to help us. Try calling `$scope.apply();` after `$scope.initGet();` inside your `setActiveTab ` function, though this shouldn't be necessary, but please, try this just for a shot in the dark.

Comment: @Alisson It didn't show any error, but the view still didn't change at all. Thanks for your advise. Anything I can try?

Comment: What happens if you do something in your callback of the .get and replace $scope.userRecipes.push(obj) with $scope.userRecipes = [{name: "test", category: "test", ingredients: "test", instructions: "test"}] does it get updated then? If so, you may need to push the  temp copy of the original userRecipes array and then update the userRecipes array with the newData.

Comment: @tina how are you calling `setActiveTab`? Another thing, the `activeTab` you used in ng-class is not updated inside your `setActiveTab` function, because it's outside `ng-controller="userRecipeController"` div, and I guess `setActiveTab` is declared inside this `userRecipeController`.

Comment: Additionally, I can't see why changing the array and explicitly calling apply would make things not to change in view. I think what you see in your view somehow is not the same array object. Looking in the browser's inspector, how many divs with the userRecipeController can you see? Are you by any chance creating these tabs dynamically? Try putting your div with ng-class statement inside the div with the controller, and check if it solves.